# Angular 8 Component / Service: How to retrieve data from async function in service

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await

In my service, I am able to connect to firebase realtime db and retrieve the information I want. However, when I try to call the method from a component, the result is always 'undefined'.

service.ts

```
async getUserSettings(userID : string) {
    const firebaseToken = await 

this.angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true);
    let searchParams = new HttpParams();
    searchParams = searchParams.set('auth', firebaseToken);
    searchParams = searchParams.append('id', userID);

 this.http.get<{ [userID: string]: SettingsModel }>(API.DB_URL + API.userSettings,
  {
    params: searchParams
  })
  .pipe(
    map(responseData => {
      let settings : SettingsModel;
      for (const key in responseData) {
        if (responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          if(responseData[key].id === userID) {
            settings = responseData[key];
          }
          // postsArray.push({ ...responseData[key], id: key });
        }
      }
    return settings;
    }),

    catchError(errorResponse => {
    return throwError(errorResponse);
    })
    )
      .subscribe(setting => {
        this.retrievedSettings = setting;
        return this.retrievedSettings;
      });
```

}

component

```
getUserSettings() {
      const userID = this.authenticationService.getUserId();
      this.userSettings = this.dbService.getUserSettings(userID)
      .then(responseData => {
        console.log(responseData);
      });
```

the responseData always returns undefined

Comment: 1. are u getting any error? if yes show us, 2. are u sure u getting the reponse from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getUserSettings` doesn't have a return statement. So normally that function would return `undefined`. But because this is an `async` function it will return a `Promise` around that `undefined`.

To fix this, change the line where you do the HTTP request:

```
this.http.get<...>()
```

To return the observable that yields the value you want:

```
return this.http.get<...>()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below strategy:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}


this.http.get<any>(url).subscribe((response: any) => {
          // handle the response
});
```